# AmCharts Stock Chart Negative Value

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have an AmCharts Stock and i get follow error. What is mean 'Invalid negative value for attribute width="-26"'.

Error: Invalid negative value for  attribute width="-26"d.SVGRenderer.d.Class.setAttr @ amcharts.js:49d.AmDObject.d.Class.setAttr @ amcharts.js:46d.SimpleChartScrollbar.d.Class.updateScrollbarSize @ amcharts.js:33d.ChartScrollbar.d.Class.zoomScrollbar @ amcharts.js:35d.ChartScrollbar.d.Class.timeZoom @ amcharts.js:34e.AmSerialChart.e.Class.zoomScrollbar @ serial.js:13e.AmSerialChart.e.Class.timeZoom @ serial.js:11e.AmSerialChart.e.Class.zoom @ serial.js:8e.AmSerialChart.e.Class.drawChart @ serial.js:8e.AmSerialChart.e.Class.initChart @ serial.js:3d.AmChart.d.Class.validateData @

Comment: Try posting your chart code and data or creating a fiddle/codepen.

Comment: Oh absolutly it is about this line; firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 58);
I shouldn't minus day number then first day.